# Add item into each subarray python

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation

I have an array `arr_ = [['a', 'b'], ['x', 'y']]`
I want to put at the beginning of each subarray the character `!`
so it should look kile this `[['!', 'a', 'b'], ['!', 'x', 'y']]`
this is what i've done so far:

```py
def concat(*args):
    return ['!', *args]
arr_ = [['a', 'b'], ['x', 'y']]
n = map(concat, arr_)
print(list(n))
```

but the result is `[['!', ['a', 'b']], ['!', ['x', 'y']]]`
What should i do?

Comment: Rather than `['!', *args]`, you could use `['!'] + args`

Comment: @RobertSeaman That won't work as the only change...

Comment: Yeh I didn't see the `*args` in the function arguments. Thanks @Tomerikoo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove the `*` in the argument of the mapper:

```
def concat(args):
    return ['!', *args]
arr_ = [['a', 'b'], ['x', 'y']]
n = map(concat, arr_)
list(n)
>>> [['!', 'a', 'b'], ['!', 'x', 'y']]
```

what happening is you packing and then unpacking the lists in each iteration...

when you add `*` to the argument you turn in into a list that contains 1 item.
when u skip this stage you can the real list and unpack it with * in the list statement `return ['!', *args]` which is equal to do : `['!'] + args` to add the `'!'` in the beginning

Answer (score 1):

this would work as expected if you did def concat(args):
What's happening is if you do *args as the parameter, every parameter you pass in will be put into a list stored in `*args`
And you're passing in things like `['a', 'b']`
So that will be put into a list so really args is: `[['a', 'b']]`
and then in your return you unpack that list
but it only contains one element, that being the original list
so you get `['!', ['a', 'b']]`

just a note, map is generally considered unpythonic since we also have list comprehensions:
`n = [concat(inner) for inner in arr_]`

you could go one step further and do this:
`n = [['!'] + inner for inner in arr_]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to explain the bug in your code. But I found another way to do it.

```
arr = [['a', 'b'], ['x', 'y']]
X = []
for i in arr:
    X.append(['!'] + i)
print(X)
```

Output:

```
[['!', 'a', 'b'], ['!', 'x', 'y']]
```

Using List Comprehension:

```
arr = [['a', 'b'], ['x', 'y']]
X = [['!'] + x for x in arr]
print(X)
```

Output:

```
[['!', 'a', 'b'], ['!', 'x', 'y']]
```